# Binding RadioButton GroupName

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a "ListView" using a "DataTemplate" as follows("UserControl"):

```
<ListBox VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
       SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding Source}" Visibility="{Binding Visibility}">
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="{Binding Orientation}"/>
  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
<ListBox.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
          <RadioButton
            GroupName="{Binding GroupName}"
            Foreground="Black"
            Margin="5,2"
            IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsSelected}">
            <RadioButton.Resources>
              <!--Unchecked state-->
              <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MaterialDesignCheckBoxOff" Color="#ced4da"/>
              <!--Checked state-->
              <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidBrush" Color="#3e97eb"/>
            </RadioButton.Resources>
            <ContentPresenter/>
          </RadioButton>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</ListBox.Resources>
```

I use this "ListBox"("UserControl") four times in "MainWindowView" so I have to use the "GroupName". but the "Binding GroupName" does not work.

***Update***
My problem solved:

```
IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected,
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                            Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Comment: Can you share your `Model` class? I wanted to know where is your `GroupName` property is.

Comment: @dhilmathy Thanks, My problem Solved by IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Mode=TwoWay}"